# How to import implicit classes through nested contexts

Tags: scala, class, import, nested, implicit

The following fails to compile on the last line:

```
// importing implicit class thru two levels
object Foo {
  implicit class IntWithSquare(x: Int) {
    def square = x*x
  }
}
object Bar {
    import Foo._
    println(4.square) // this works
}
import Bar._
println(5.square) // this fails to compile
```

How can we force the export of imported implicit class from within Bar? The motivation for this is to keep object Foo neat by defining all implicits in a separate file. Same problem exists for other definitions coming from Foo into Bar. But, a simple re-definition of the top names works in such cases:

```
// importing regular definitions and types thru two levels
object Foo {
  def someBigFunc(): Int = {
    42
  }
  type Word = String
}
object Bar {
    import Foo._
    val someBigFunc = Foo.someBigFunc _
    type Word = Foo.Word
}
import Bar._
someBigFunc()
val w: Word = "word"
```

Comment: Short answer you can't export an import, mainly because an import is nothing more than a compile time alias, it is not doing anything. - However, if all you want is to split the syntax definitions across multiple files but have a single import then there is a pretty straightforward pattern for that, check how libraries like **cats** and **neotypes** work.

Comment: Also note that in Scala 3, the `export` clause could be interesting for you.

Answer (score 2):

The approach used to do what you want to achieve is usually to define `trait`s and have an `object` extending all wanted traits.

```scala
trait Foo {
  // Define implicit stuff here
}

trait Fii {
  // Define other implicits here
}

object Bar extends Foo with Fii

import Bar._ // will provide the implicits from Foo and Fii
```